# Intent.getData().getPath() not returning the actual path?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

I am designing an application where the user selects a text file from the memory and the app speaks it out. I am using Intents to do it.
My `onActivityResult()` looks like this.

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data){
 if(resCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null){

        Uri u = data.getData();
        String str = u.getPath();
        Toast.makeText(this, "str", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //File file = new File(str);}}
```

So initially, I was getting the path using which I was able to read the file. But know, it is returning `/external/file/6433`. No matter how deep my file is situated, it will return `/external/file/number`. 
Kindly tell me what I need to do to get the actual path i.e. `/storage/emulated/0/`.

Comment: you just need `Uri u`, not any path

Answer (score 1):

The string that you get from intent actually is the URI for the file. You can use this method to get the actual path. I put this code in my Utils class. The code is quite long. You can refer to actual Utils class here : [Utils.getPath](https://pastebin.com/59GxGTnM)

```
public static String getActualPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }

            // TODO handle non-primary volumes
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                    split[1]
            };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}
```

and make some changes onActivityResult

```
 Uri u = data.getData();
 String filePath = Utils.getActualPath(this, u);
 Toast.makeText(this, filePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: you should not use `getPath()` method, what you should use is `Uri uri` instead

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But getPath that I used above is not generic getPath. It just the name of the DocumentContract method I created in my Utils class. Or are you talking about another getPath method?

Edit: Change getPath -> getActualPath

Comment: no, i am talking about `getPath` method you posted above, there is no guarantee that `Uri` content will be stored in a file (and you will have access to that file), instead use `Uri` and `ContentResolver` API

Comment: If you open the link above, I do use ContentResolver in getDataColumn method.

Comment: again, if you want to get the content of an `Uri`, use `ContentResolver#openInputStream(Uri uri)` / `ContentResolver#openFileDescriptor(Uri uri, String mode)` - there is no guarantee that `Uri` content will be stored in a file (and you will have access to that file)